Airflow DAG Scheduling Issue: Passing Correct Execution Date for Monthly and Weekly Runs
I'm facing an issue with Airflow where my DAGs are not passing the correct execution date to the queries within the DAGs. I have two DAGs, one scheduled to run monthly on the first of the month, and another scheduled weekly on Wednesdays. Here’s how each DAG is configured:
Monthly DAG
@dag(
    dag_id="monthly_dag",
    description="Monthly pipeline",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 1),
    schedule_interval="0 18 1 * *",  # Every month on the 1st day at 18:00 UTC
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 3,
        "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
)

Weekly DAG
@dag(
    dag_id="weekly_dag",
    description="Weekly pipeline",
    schedule="0 8 * * 3",  # Every Wednesday at 08:00 UTC
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 26),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
)

Problem
The monthly DAG, when triggered on 2024-11-01, logs a logical run date of 2024-10-01, resulting in the date passed to queries as 2024-10-01 rather than the expected 2024-11-01.
As for the weekly DAG, the next execution date (2024-10-30) was missed, and the DAG didn't get triggered.
How can I configure both DAGs to ensure they run with the correct execution date (the actual day they’re scheduled to run) so that this date is accurately passed through to downstream tasks and queries?

The logical date is determined when the next run is scheduled. So the logical date will be the date of the previous month in your case. It is counterintuitive but it is the expected behavior. Read more about it here: https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/scheduling-in-airflow/.
As for your weekly dag, I’m not sure, but it is possible that your start date is too late, for the same reason given above.
